# Using variadic template arguments to resolve a lambda signature

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda, metaprogramming

While there's a lot of stuff floating out there about getting the return type of any templated callback function/method (including lambdas of course), I'm having an extremely hard time finding information about resolving the full call signature of a lambda function. At least in gcc 4.7 it seems to be an edge case where the normal tricks (see below) don't work. Here's what I'm trying to do and have so far (a stripped down version of course)...

```
template<typename Sig>
struct invokable_type { };

template<typename R, typename...As>
struct invokable_type<R(As...)> {
   static constexpr size_t n = sizeof...(As);
   typedef R(callable_type)(As...);
   template<size_t i>
   struct arg {
       typedef typename peel_type<i, As...> type;
   };
};
```

`peel_type<size_t, typename...>` is not included here for brevity but it's a simple argument type peeler (I think there's one built in to C++11, but I never bothered to look). It's unimportant for this question.

Then, of course, specializations (and further properties/typedefs) exist for a myriad of callable types such as `R(*)(As...)`, `R(&)(As...)`, `(R(T::*)(As...)`, `std::function<R(As...)>`, method cv qualifiers, method lvalue/rvalue qualifiers, etc, etc, etc.

Then, somewhere down the road we have a lovely function or method (function here, doesn't matter) that looks like...

```
template<typename C, typename...As>
static void do_something(C&& callback, As&&...as) {
    do_something_handler<invokable_type<C>::n, As...>::something(std::forward<C>(callback), std::forward<As>(as)...);
}
```

Never mind what `do_something_handler` does... it's entirely immaterial. The problem lies with lambda functions.

For all possible generic invokable signatures I've specialized for (which appears to be all but non-STL functors), this works beautifully when `do_something()` is called with them as the first argument (template deduction fully works). However, lambda functions result in an uncaptured type signature, resulting in `invokable_type<Sig>` being used, which means things like `::n` and `::args<0>::type` simply don't exist.

Not-a-problem example...

```
void something(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

... and later...

```
do_something(something, 7, 23);
```

Problem example...

```
do_something([](int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }, 7, 23);
```

If I understand lambda functions correctly, the compiler is *likely* to compile this lambda to a static function within the "namespace" of the defining scope (gcc certainly seems to). For the life of me I can't figure out what the signature actually is though. It looks like it definitely has one that should be deducible via template specialization (based on error reporting).

Another tangential question is even if there is a signature I can use, how cross-compiler dangerous this this? Are lambda compilation signatures standardized or is it all across the board?

Comment: The type of a lambda-expression is a class type (the closure type) with a function call operator. I'm not sure what `typedef R(invokable_type)(As...)` is, though.

Comment: @DyP: lambda expressions *are not* explicitly class type. There is no requirement in the C++11 spec for this to be the case and certainly no need if no capturing is done. Please point out the spec if you know this is the case and I stand corrected (and have something to work with, which is good :). As for the typedef, it's the bare typedef for the signature of the function. It's not a pointer or ref function or those would be `typedef R(*invokable_type)(As...)` and `typedef R(&invokable_type)(As...)` respectively. Like I said, I specialized for all of that.

Comment: [expr.prim.lambda]/3 "The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type*"

Comment: Are you then re-using, i.e. hiding, the identifier `invokable_type`? It's the template name, therefore the *injected-class-name*. (Also, I think a `;` is missing.)

Comment: @DyP: 1) in response to your second response, thanks, I'll dig around that; know how to capture the type? 2) No, invokable_type is not hidden, and, again, even in a simple example works perfectly for all tried non-lambda instances. 3) Probably, I literally typed this from scratch as a conceptual, but not explicitly runnable, example. I'll correct the syntax if that's the case.

Comment: [Works for me, using clang++3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9cb1e0e7a7203e1)

Comment: @DyP: So you think it's a gcc 4.7 issue (I suspected maybe)?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this function typedef syntax, hence I'm asking. But to me, `typedef R(&new_name)(As...);` is reasonable, whereas I don't know what `typedef R(invokable_type)(As...);` means. clang++ gives the error: *member `decompose` has the same name as its class* (for my linked example)

Comment: Wrong button :) If you try my example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) and it doesn't compile under g++4.7, then I think its a g++4.7 issue ;) g++4.8.1 also compiles my example.

Comment: @Dyp: Your example seems to work on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8M1WBj)

Comment: @DyP: I put this in chat, but I'll put this here for posterity: That might be a gcc-ism also... i'm not entirely sure. It's effecively a decay so that a function can be passed as do_something(some_function) rather than by ref or pointer. I think this is allowed by C as well (but is cast as a pointer?). I'm not entirely sure. It is, however, how gcc deduces everything for their std::function implementation, so I doubt it's that out of touch with standards.

Comment: @DyP: Excellent... I guess... but frustrating. At least I'm not on MSVC.

Comment: @DyP: Submit that answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: @DyP: Yes. It's exactly what I expected *should* happen (for all the reasons you pointed out both in comments, and in answer [full answer btw, thanks]), which is why I've banged my head against a wall for a couple days, and the fact that it's a problem in gcc<=4.7 but not gcc 4.8 is even more to the point. Your concise example is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing up and extending from the comments:

Per [expr.prim.lambda]/3, the type of a *lambda-expression* is a class type, just like "ordinary, named function object types":

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type* [...]

Further down, /5 specifies:

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* has a public `inline` function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are described by the *lambda-expression*’s *parameter-declaration-clause* and *trailing-return-type* respectively. This function call operator is declared `const` (9.3.1) if and only if the *lambda-expression*’s parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable. It is neither virtual nor declared
>   `volatile`. [...]

(it then continues by specifying attributes and exception-specifications)

Which means that the lambda `[](int p){ return p/2.0; }` behaves in this regard exactly like

```
struct named_function_object
{
    double operator() (int p) const { return p/2.0; }
};
```

Therefore, your first specialization

```
template<typename R, typename...As>
struct invokable_type<R(As...)>;
```

should already be able to deal with lambdas. The SSCCE

```
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct decompose;

template<class Ret, class T, class... Args>
struct decompose<Ret(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    constexpr static int n = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<class T>
int deduce(T t)
{
    return decompose<decltype(&T::operator())>::n;
}

struct test
{
    void operator() (int) const {}
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << deduce(test{}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << deduce([](int){}) << std::endl;
}
```

compiles fine on recent versions of clang++ and g++. It seems the problem is related to g++4.7

---

Further research shows that g++-4.7.3 compiles the above example.

The problem might be related to the misconception that a *lambda-expression* would yield a function type. If we define `do_something` as

```
template<class C>
void do_something(C&&)
{
    std::cout << invokable_type<C>::n << std::endl;
}
```

Then for a call like `do_something( [](int){} )`, the template parameter `C` will be deduced to the closure type (no reference), i.e. a class type. The analogous case for the `struct test` defined above, would be `do_something( test{} )`, in which case `C` would be deduced to `test`.

The specialization of `invokable_type` that is instantiated is therefore the *general case*

```
template<class T>
struct invokable_type;
```

as `T` in both cases is not a "composite type" like a pointer or function type. This general case can be used by assuming it only takes a pure class type, and then using the member `T::operator()` of that class type:

```
template<class T>
struct invokable_type
{
    constexpr static int n = invokable_type<&T::operator()>::n;
};
```

or, as [Potatoswatter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153285/potatoswatter) put it, via inheritance

```
template<class T>
struct invokable_type
    : invokable_type<&T::operator()>
{};
```

[Potatoswatter's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19149751/420683) however is more general and probably better, relying on a SFINAE check for the existance of `T::operator()`, which can provide a better diagnostic message if the operator cannot be found.

N.B. If you prefix a lambda-expression that doesn't capture anything with a unary `+`, it'll be converted to a pointer-to-function. `do_something( +[](int){} )` will work with a specialization `invokable_type<Return(*)(Args...)>`.

Comment: Le sigh... by the time C++14 is out, C++11 still won't be complete across major compilers/distributions. I'm not complaining about the future though :)

Comment: How does his code deal with lambdas… I don't see anything that mentions `T::operator ()`. What you need is, given a type, get the signature of its member `operator()` if any. I'm baffled by all the excessive boilerplate in the Q. As for this answer, you have counted the size of the argument list in `T()` and didn't touch the lambda.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It doesn't in this simple example (as stated in the question), but the problem relates to the fact that you can't do `auto fn = std::function([](){})` in gcc 4.7 and properly resolve that without specifying template parameters... that's the underlying problem.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And, more to the point, instead of commenting, post a solution that works and tell me why it works. Your argument doesn't work (read the full question with my points about specializing for everything imaginable), but post something that works in 4.7 and explain how/why, and I'll change the vote.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've changed my example to make it more useful and deduce the actual arguments from the function object / closure type. I got confused at some point with the `T()` syntax (there's also an alternative syntax for functions and function pointers, I somehow must have mixed them up).

Comment: @DyP I don't have a copy of 4.7 and I don't know of an online compiler providing it in C++11 mode, but see my answer. It's written in proper metafunction style, not depending on the form of the input.

Comment: @mr.stobbe I just tried with g++-4.7.3 and it worked. See updated answer.

Comment: @DyP: Nice! Didn't know about the `+` trick. That doesn't help with this particular question (we're talking about "genfiying" template chains) but that nota bene will definitely be priceless. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As DyP mentions, lambda functors are guaranteed to have a public `operator ()`. Note that `operator ()` cannot be `static` or non-member.

(A type can also be callable due to the existence of a conversion operator to function pointer type, and stateless lambdas do have such conversion operators, but they still must provide `operator ()`.

You can get the signature of `operator ()` using `decltype( & T::operator() )`, provided there is only one overload, which is guaranteed for lambdas. This results in a pointer to member function type. You can use a metafunction to strip the `T::` part off, or write metafunction queries against the PTMF directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template< typename t, std::size_t n, typename = void >
struct function_argument_type;

template< typename r, typename ... a, std::size_t n >
struct function_argument_type< r (*)( a ... ), n >
    { typedef typename std::tuple_element< n, std::tuple< a ... > >::type type; };

template< typename r, typename c, typename ... a, std::size_t n >
struct function_argument_type< r (c::*)( a ... ), n >
    : function_argument_type< r (*)( a ... ), n > {};

template< typename r, typename c, typename ... a, std::size_t n >
struct function_argument_type< r (c::*)( a ... ) const, n >
    : function_argument_type< r (c::*)( a ... ), n > {};

template< typename ftor, std::size_t n >
struct function_argument_type< ftor, n,
    typename std::conditional< false, decltype( & ftor::operator () ), void >::type >
    : function_argument_type< decltype( & ftor::operator () ), n > {};


int main() {
    auto x = []( int, long, bool ){};
    std::cout << typeid( function_argument_type< decltype(x), 0 >::type ).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid( function_argument_type< decltype(x), 1 >::type ).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid( function_argument_type< decltype(x), 2 >::type ).name() << '\n';
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57cd7bb76267ffda

Comment: Can you redo this as an invocation like was the example where constexpr arg count n is passed to another handler where nothing is known about the callback except C (Callable type, C&& in the example)?

Comment: @mr.stobbe "Can you redo this" is not a polite introduction. I have provided the functionality of `invokable_type::arg` from your question. If you want to encapsulate it in something else, it's up to you.

Comment: Well, I don't think that was particularly impolite but I'm sorry if I offended you. It works given, but that's `auto x = [lambda]`, which is not the question at hand. If you replace `decltype(x)` with `decltype([](int, long, bool){})` throughout, it doesn't work.

Comment: @mr.stobbe The error message (in clang++3.4 and g++4.8.1) should be enlightening ;) "lambda expression in an unevaluated operand". You can deduce it via a function to make it work.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Okay, now extend that to the scenario in the question. That's not very "enlightening". We're not talking about replacing `auto x` with a direct lambda. We're talking about why `std::function([](int i) { })` doesn't resolve to `std::function<void(int)>(void(int)&&)` or `std::function<void(T::&)(int)>(void(T::&)(int)&&))` when it should. I wasn't being verbose about the chain of invocation for nothing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Let me make this clear... I want you to be right, it just doesn't work for generic specialization of type struct traits of C, given only C, when you see what I'm asking and the issues (and yes, I think I understand it). In gcc 4.7, all type representations of a direct lambda seem to have a bad signature which results in `<typename C> call(C&& c) { traits<C>::whatever }` not resolving because C doesn't include a simple `C::operator()(As...);`. As far as I can tell... again, *please* prove me wrong.

Comment: @mr.stobbe The previous reply was not from me. I provided a metafunction which you can use from any context given a type T, which may be a user-defined class with one `operator()`, a lambda, a function pointer, or a member function pointer. Other specializations are possible. You claim that a GCC bug prevents declaring a local lambda function. Perhaps true, but not really relevant to the question at hand. I have to assume you already have a type upon which you will perform queries.

Comment: By the way, `std::function([](){}` is invalid. `std::function` is a class template, not a function template, so deduction doesn't work. You seem to expect deduction to cause lambdas to convert to something else, but deduction never causes any conversions, and each lambda expression has its own unique class type. It is that type which you must pass to a query.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Relized that after the post. Moot point though because my comments are still the same. Look at the chain of calls... if `template<typename C> call(C&& c) { std::function(c); }` *can work* (which it doesn't in gcc 4.7). then `template<typename C> call(C&& c) { typedef invokable<C>::whatever dowith; }` *should work*. This is why I was asking you to put it in the same context as the question (tried by the way; didn't work because it's essentially my same post, but gave it a go; something I'm missing?).

Comment: @mr.stobbe The sequence of tokens `std::function(c)` is always invalid unless you have defined something else named `std`. Please post a new question, because we've left the scope of this one.

Comment: Ummm... having a really hard time to respond to this one. Yeah... I forgot to include a header. We're talking abstractly about template parameter deduction and specialization and that's what you think? Really? Glad I down voted you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38518/discussion-between-mr-stobbe-and-potatoswatter)

Comment: Well, since they don't seem to be around, for posterity, I was saying that, the fact that `std::function(c)` doesn't resolve to `std::function<C>(c)`, given a templated function of `template<typename C>(C&& c)` is *the same* problem as `template<...> invokable_type<C>` not resolving. Either, a) A signature specialization is missing, or b) it's not possible. DyP responded with what makes the most sense. Sorry, I'm a little pissed at Potatoswatter's disregard of the entire complexity of recursive template param deduction at the end there. I just woke up as a novice and posted this question?

Comment: `std::function(c)` not resolving isn't a problem, because it's nonsense code. `template<typename C>(C&& c)` likewise cannot occur anywhere; you're just babbling. You have an odd perspective about downvotes, but enjoy it if that's what makes you happy.